# Why won't the code correctly identify numbers and/or letters in a string?

Tags: javascript, string

I want to devise a way that allows the code to identify letters, my code is:

```
var thingToTest = "Some Random String"
var thing = thingToTest.charAt(0);
if (thing = "some random letter that isn't in the code") {
     alert("This should not come up...");
};
```

However, the alert always pops up, whether the letter is the right one or not.  I have updated all of my software and restarted my computer, but it never works.  I am sure that I am doing something wrong, but I don't know what it is. I have spent a lot of time trying to figure it out.

Comment: `=` vs `==` (again!).

Comment: `thing = ...` with only 1 `=` assigns the variable, it does't compare it.

Comment: thing = "string" should be "thing == string"

Comment: There is a thing which is called string validation. Google for regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `==` or `===` to perform an equality check in JavaScript:

```
var thingToTest = "Some Random String"
var thing = thingToTest.charAt(0);
if (thing === "some random letter that isn't in the code") {
//        ^^^
     alert("This _will not_ come up...");
};
```

______

In your example you are performing an assignment rather than an equality check within your `if` clause.

Assignments evaluate to their right-hand-side expression. So the `if` clause will resolve to `"some random letter that isn't in the code"`, which is truthy. Therefore, the body of the `if` clause is executed.

Answer (score 1):

`=` is an assignment operator.

E.g:

```
var a = 5;
```

`==` and `===` are comparison operators, `==` can check only the values of both variables.

E.g:

```
if(a == 5){
  //success statements 
}
```

But `===` can check both values and datatypes of both variables.

E.g:

```
if(a === 5){ // it will check typeof(a) == typeof(RHS value)
  //success statements
}
```